# Import outdated MySQL dump using console

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sql, dump

I have a mysql dump file created by outdated MySQL version. I have no access to that server (console).

If i use this command on my current server:

```
mysql -u user -p dbname < dump.sql
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 12547: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
 the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Of course i cannot show this file, but i stacked searching solution. I need to import this file into my current database.

P.S. Source database may have non-utf charset, but current has one.

What should i do? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is on line 1?

Comment: -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe you have a BOM in that file?

Comment: I've changed a `dbname` encoding on my server to `utf8_general_ci`, and my command worked for more than 6 mins, created ~90% of structure, but then failed with SAME message. I think it was not completed.. I heard there are some 'compatibility' options in MYSQL...

Comment: actually what is more interesting: what is at line 12547 ?